# Sum selected elements in dict of dicts in Python using one liner instead of for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, nested-loops, simplify

I used the below dict comprehension

```
dimer = {(ab+cd):{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0} for cd in 'ACGT' for ab in 'ACGT'}
```

to generate a dict of dicts,dimer:

```
dimer = {"AA":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}, "AC":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}, "AG":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}, "AT":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}, "CA":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}, "CC":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}, "CG":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}, "CT":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}, "GA":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}, "GC":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}, "GG":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}, "GT":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}, "TA":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}, "TC":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}, "TT":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}, "TG":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}}
```

However, now I want to sum up selected elements,

If I hardcode them out, it would be like

```
total_A = dimer["AA"]["1"]+dimer["CA"]["1"]+dimer["GA"]["1"]+dimer["TA"]["1"]+dimer["AA"]["2"]+dimer["CA"]["2"]+dimer["GA"]["2"]+dimer["TA"]["2"]+dimer["AA"]["3"]+dimer["CA"]["3"]+dimer["GA"]["3"]+dimer["TA"]["3"]
total_C = dimer["AC"]["1"]+dimer["CC"]["1"]+dimer["GC"]["1"]+dimer["TC"]["1"]+dimer["AC"]["2"]+dimer["CC"]["2"]+dimer["GC"]["2"]+dimer["TC"]["2"]+dimer["AC"]["3"]+dimer["CC"]["3"]+dimer["GC"]["3"]+dimer["TC"]["3"]
total_G = dimer["AG"]["1"]+dimer["CG"]["1"]+dimer["GG"]["1"]+dimer["TG"]["1"]+dimer["AG"]["2"]+dimer["CG"]["2"]+dimer["GG"]["2"]+dimer["TG"]["2"]+dimer["AG"]["3"]+dimer["CG"]["3"]+dimer["GG"]["3"]+dimer["TG"]["3"]
total_T = dimer["AT"]["1"]+dimer["CT"]["1"]+dimer["GT"]["1"]+dimer["TT"]["1"]+dimer["AT"]["2"]+dimer["CT"]["2"]+dimer["GT"]["2"]+dimer["TT"]["2"]+dimer["AT"]["3"]+dimer["CT"]["3"]+dimer["GT"]["3"]+dimer["TT"]["3"]
```

The best approach I have come up with to simplify it is using nested for-loops:

```
total_0 = {i:0 for i in 'ACGT'}   
for i in 'ACGT':    
    for j in 'ACGT':
        for k in '123':
            total_0[i] += dimer[j+i][k]
```

I was wondering if there is any method to sum them up using a one liner?

I also have another nested for-loops:

```
row_sum = {i:{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0} for i in 'ACGT'}   
for i in 'ACGT':    
    for j in 'ACGT':
        for k in '123': 
            row_sum[i][k] += float(dimer[i+j][k])
```

The hardcode version is like:

```
row_sum = {"A":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0},"C":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0},"G":{"G":0,"2":0,"3":0},"T":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0}} 
for i in range(1,4,1): 
    row_sum["A"][str(i)] = float(dimer["AA"][str(i)]+dimer["AC"][str(i)]+dimer["AG"][str(i)]+dimer["AT"][str(i)])
    row_sum["C"][str(i)] = float(dimer["CA"][str(i)]+dimer["CC"][str(i)]+dimer["CG"][str(i)]+dimer["CT"][str(i)])
    row_sum["G"][str(i)] = float(dimer["GA"][str(i)]+dimer["GC"][str(i)]+dimer["GG"][str(i)]+dimer["GT"][str(i)])
    row_sum["T"][str(i)] = float(dimer["TA"][str(i)]+dimer["TC"][str(i)]+dimer["TG"][str(i)]+dimer["TT"][str(i)])
```

I am also wondering if there is any method to sum the second nested for-loop up using a one liner?

Sorry I am really new to Python. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: New to Java? This is Python!

Comment: Why do you use `"1"`, `"2"`, etc. instead of `1`, `2`, etc? Dict keys don't have to be strings.

Comment: @amaurea Thank you! I thought that dict keys should be strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can collapse the 3 loops into one using a cartesian product like this.

```
from itertool import product
row_sum = {i: {"1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 0} for i in NT}   
for i, j, k in product('ACGT', 'ACGT', '123'):    
    row_sum[i][k] += float(dimer[i + j][k])
```

Here is a one liner, but it's probably hard for you to follow if you are new to Python

```
{i: sum(sum(dimer[i + j].values()) for j in 'ACGT') for i in 'ACGT'}
```

Comment: Great! That one liner was exactly I was looking for. I have been checking the list comprehension document for 1 hour but could not really come up with the exact code to get it in one line.

Comment: I have tested and believes that the second one liner should be {i: sum(sum(dimer[j+i].values()) for j in 'ACGT') for i in 'ACGT'} instead

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this would mesh with the rest of your program, but it may be worth switching to a different data structure. If you represent your collection of dimers as a single `numpy` array of integers, you will have your oneliners, and also see large speedups. Your dimers could for example be represented like this:

```
import numpy as np
dimer = np.zeros((4,4,3),dtype=int)
```

Here 0,1,2,3 in the first index represents whether the first element in the dimer is A,C,G,T, and similarly for the second index, while the third index contains the three different cases you label "1", "2" or "3". So your `dimer["AG"]["1"]` would here be `dimer[0,2,0]` (since numpy counts from zero).

The advantage of using a structure like this is

1. It is much faster and more memory efficient if your data set becomes large (if you have 300000 elements per dimer instead of 3, for example).
2. There are lots of functions available for manipluating `numpy` arrays. For example, `np.sum(dimer,2)` would give you the total count of the elements of each dimer.

The aggregate statistics you want could be computed as:

```
total_0 = np.sum(dimer, (0,2))
row_sum = np.sum(dimer, 1)
```

As an illustration of the speed differences, for your problem size, the the `dict` approach with for loops takes 20 µs to compute `total_0`, while the `numpy` sum takes 5.7 µs. For a 1000 times larger problem, where each dimer has 3000 members, the `dict` approach takes 22 ms while `numpy` takes 31 µs. And for a 1,000,000 times larger problem `dict`s take 24.5 s while `numpy` takes 24.3 ms. So for large problem sizes, `numpy` is 1000 times faster than using dicts.